# How to print the contents of an array to a label in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, label

I want to display the contents of the Array from a label with a comma between each number.
num1 - num6 are integer variables converted from textboxes.
So Far I have done this.

```
int[] number = new int [6] {num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6};

Array.Sort(number);

lblAnswer3.Text = number.ToString();
```

The output of this code is: System.Int32[]

I would like the output to be: num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6 in ascending order.

Comment: use `Join` method of array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily concat IEnumerables and arrays with [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx):

```
lblAnswer3.Text = string.Join(", ", number);
```

Comment: +1 I didn't realize String.Join could work on IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @BradleyDotNET that overload was introduced in .NET 4

Comment: In .NET2 you need something like `string.Join(","; Array.ConvertAll(number, delegate(int i) { return i.ToString(); }));`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Linq:

```
lblAnswer3.Text = number.OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);
```

Comment: -1. All of that is unnecessary.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Kind of harsh to down-vote a solution that works, isn't it? Shouldn't we just upvote the solutions that we like the best and down vote ones that either don't work or don't answer the question?

Comment: @RufusL I'm not sure *I* would downvote it, but this solution is over-complicated enough that I could understand it being regarded as "not useful". The `OrderBy` might be required for ascending order though (if they aren't already ordered).

Comment: @RufusL: the purpose of scoring answers is so that future readers are more likely to choose answers with higher scores. I want to make sure future readers are _less_ likely to choose this one. If the OP is concerned about rep points, then the OP can delete the answer and get the two points back.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Fair enough.

Comment: "the purpose of scoring answers is so that future readers are more likely to choose answers with higher scores" stating the obvious in a condescending tone only makes you look like a jerk. the answer is not wrong. you can argue it's not as efficient but it's an alternative

Comment: @bb01234: I didn't say it wouldn't work. I mean that if I were doing a code review and saw that code, I'd ask you to change it. If I were your supervisor and saw that code in a code review, I'd _tell_ you to change it. And, BTW, it's _not_ obvious. Many people don't get why we have upvotes and downvotes here, or get the wrong idea about them.

Comment: It IS obvious, and it is explained in the tour and in the site help. Quality of answers is important but when a newbie asks something it is beneficial to be offered alternatives. For example: what if he had an array of doubles and wanted to string.Format them? A simple string.join would not be sufficient.