# Trying to display an array of numbers onto label

Tags: c#, .net

```
private static void Display(params Object[] things)
{
    foreach (Object num in number)
       Label5.Text = "{0} ", + num;
}
```

I'm not really sure what to really do. I want to display all the input numbers onto `label5`, but I'm not really sure how to do it.

For example: I have a `textBox` and the user enters in `23, 50, 89, 73, 40`, etc into the `textBox` and I want to display the numbers the user entered into `label5`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the text a user has entered into a `textbox`, why not assign it directly

```
label5.Text = textbox.Text;
```

The way you want to do it, to set it from an array you can do it like this:

```
private static void Display(params Object[] things)
{
    foreach (Object num in number)
       Label5.Text = Label5.Text + String.Format("{0}, " + num);
}
```

I don't quite understand though why you pass an array ob objects into the method if you don't use them.

Comment: for somereason it says label5 does not exist in the current context, but it is displayed on the form. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: how / where do you call the `Display` method? does it have to be static?

Comment: Nvm, I get it now thank you for your help. I call the display method on main and it doesnt have to be static.

Comment: You should also re-think if the `num` has to be an `Object` the same goes for the input params

Comment: yeah my book gave me a bad explanation or a brief explanation on when to use them. Can you help me understand them a bit? or give me a link where i can go read more about it?

Comment: Hm... you can try this and go from there https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx.

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: use StringBuilder if you have large array to gain performance.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the last value by every new iteration in the for loop

do instead this:
put all the element in the array in one variable (use a StringBuilder)
and then when that is done, set the content of the label with that variable

## Example:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Object num in number){
    sb.append(num);
}
Label5.Content = sb.ToString;
```

## Edit

adding comma to separate the values:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var comma = ""; 
foreach (Object num in number){
    sb.append(comma).append(num);
    comma = ", ";
}
Label5.Content = sb.ToString;
```

Comment: The output of this would be `2350897340` missing the commas, also you missed `()` on the last `ToString`

Comment: Great, I upvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

To concat `IEnumerable<T>` items into a `string`, try using [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Label5.Text = String.Join(", ", numbers);
```

Comment: this is a pretty cool way...

Comment: Surprising that noone come up with [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434458/how-to-print-the-contents-of-an-array-to-a-label-in-c-sharp) before...